# JavaFx erron in running

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

i have got a problem with javafx. i created my fxml file in SceneBuilder and put it in the same directory with package folder. here are codes:

```
public class Main  extends Application    {



public static void main(String[] args){
    launch(args);
}   

@Override
public void start(Stage window) throws Exception {
    Pane mainPane = (Pane)FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("../sas.fxml"));


    Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane);
    window.setScene(scene);
    window.show();
}
}
```

when i run this it gives me this error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$152(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$50/1323468230.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/H:/Java%20projects/JavaFx/bin/sas.fxml:7

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
at javafx.Main.start(Main.java:20)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$53/1393559157.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/186276003.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/200091476.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/237061348.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/2117255219.run(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyController
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 28 more
Exception running application javafx.Main
```

i searched solution online, most of them says that problem can be with url. but as you see in first code i wrote it like (../sas.fxml) because it is not in the same folder with java files, it is in the same folder with package folder. so any idea how to solve it? appreciate any solution

FXML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="185.0" prefWidth="349.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="MyController">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="username" layoutX="44.0" layoutY="35.0" promptText="username" />
      <Button fx:id="login" layoutX="224.0" layoutY="35.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#loginFucntion" text="Login" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

MyController.java

```
package javafx;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class MyController {

    @FXML
    private Button login;

    @FXML
    private TextField username;

    @FXML
    void loginFucntion(ActionEvent event) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the FXML file?

Comment: Don't post it in a comment, it's unreadable. [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: So do you have a MyController class in the default package?

Comment: yes added it also, but i don't think there is any problem with controller

Comment: The problem is you have the name wrong in the FXML file.

Comment: yeap. now it works. thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fx:controller` attribute requires the *fully qualified* name of the class. Since you placed `MyController` in a package called `javafx` (which, by the way, you shouldn't: that is a protected package name, so you should choose something else that is specific to your company/organization etc), you would need

```
fx:controller="javafx.MyController"
```

Since you specified just `fx:controller="MyController"`, the `FXMLLoader` is looking in the default package (i.e. in the root of the classpath) for a class called `MyController`. Since it can't find it there (it is in a different package), it is giving you a `ClassNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this line `/H:/Java%20projects/JavaFx/bin/sas.fxml:7`

I think the folder name is "Java projects". Try renaming it to "JavaProjects" or "Java_projects". The space character is converted to %20 which causes the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` to be thrown

Comment: tried but still same error. maybe i didn't save fxml file to correct directory?

Comment: I don't think that's correct. The FXMLLoader is clearly reading the FXML file, because it knows it's supposed to look for the MyController class. So clearly it has found the FXML file.

Comment: @James_D then do you have any idea why did it give such error?

Comment: I know this might be a silly suggestion, but is the MyController class compiled (does the .class file exist)

Comment: there is no problem with MyController.java it is in the same directory with Main.java